# Handling Property Accessor hidden attachment error

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I have a script which checks attachments in mail coming to the shared mailbox. It ignores hidden attachments (like the images inside the message).

It works on my computer.

When I installed it on a user's computer, sometimes it gave this error:

> Run-time error '-2147221233 (8004010f)':
> The property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B" is unknown or cannot be found.

I searched the Web and found some attachments don't have the property of hidden attachment (probably).

I tried to make an error handler.

The idea of the script is to accept the mails with PDF attachments only. With the current error handler it sometimes accepts the mails which contain other attachment type.

Here is the part of the code which checks attachments:

```vb
Private Sub objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Const PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B"

Dim myAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim allPdf As Boolean
Dim hidNum As Integer

allPdf = True
hidNum = 0

Dim pa As PropertyAccessor

Dim objWatchFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim Recip As Outlook.Recipient
Set Recip = objNS.CreateRecipient("test@mail.com")

Set objWatchFolder = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recip, olFolderInbox)

For Each myAtt In Item.Attachments
    Debug.Print myAtt.DisplayName
    Set pa = myAtt.PropertyAccessor
    
    On Error GoTo Handler
        
    If Not pa.GetProperty(PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN) Then
        If Right(LCase(myAtt.FileName), 4) <> ".pdf" Then
            allPdf = False
        End If
    Else
        hidNum = hidNum + 1
    End If
NextAtt:
Next myAtt

If allPdf = False Or Item.Attachments.Count = hidNum Then
    Item.Move objWatchFolder.Parent.Folders("Error")
End If

Set Item = Nothing
Set myAtt = Nothing
Set pa = Nothing
Set objWatchFolder = Nothing
Set Recip = Nothing

Exit Sub

Handler:
    Resume NextAtt

End Sub
```

I guess the problem is that after an error it ignores the attachment which caused the error and goes to the next one.

Can I still check an attachment type of the attachment in error handler?

And what if the hidden attachment doesn't have the hidden attachment property? Is this even possible? It would make the script useless unless there is another way to differ hidden attachments from the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the exception is by design and you need to handle it. Which is of course messy in VBA.

Use `on error resume next` / `Err.Clear` / `Err.Number` / `Err.Description` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/err-object

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it in my situation. I did something like On Error GoTo Handler, Handler:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    If Right(LCase(myAtt.FileName), 4) <> ".pdf" Then
        allPdf = False
    End If
End If
Resume NextAtt

Comment: Try "On Error Resume Next" / "Err.Clear" / call PropertyAccessor / check Err.Number

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

Const PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B"

Dim myAtt As Attachment
Dim allPdf As Boolean
Dim hidNum As Long

Dim bHidden As Boolean

allPdf = True
hidNum = 0

Dim pa As propertyAccessor
Dim objWatchFolder As Folder
Dim recip As Recipient

Set recip = Session.CreateRecipient("test@mail.com")

Set objWatchFolder = Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, olFolderInbox)

For Each myAtt In Item.Attachments

    Debug.Print myAtt.DisplayName
    Set pa = myAtt.propertyAccessor
        
    bHidden = False
    
    On Error Resume Next
    bHidden = pa.GetProperty(PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN)
    If err <> 0 Then bHidden = True ' Set True when property not found
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Consider mandatory and as soon as possible after On Error Resume Next
    
    If bHidden = False Then
        If Right(LCase(myAtt.fileName), 4) <> ".pdf" Then
            allPdf = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Else
        hidNum = hidNum + 1
    End If

Next myAtt

If allPdf = False Or Item.Attachments.count = hidNum Then
    Item.Move objWatchFolder.Parent.Folders("Error")
End If

End Sub
```